# Anyone have a simple template for creating a new syntax highlighter for a Netbeans Editor?

Tags: templates, syntax-highlighting, netbeans6.7

I'd like to throw together a basic Netbeans editor with syntax highlighting for a non-standard database language.

Initial target: highlight a set of reserved words and standard C multi-line comments.

Anyone savvy with this and could point me to a link, or a template?

One last thing: I've pulled down the Netbeans source tree before and tried to slog my way through it. Ugh. I'm looking more for a plug-in template that could do this, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the netbeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/How_to_create_support_for_a_new_language) has information on adding support for a new language. Look under point 3). It's a cumbersome process, but fairly straightforward

Comment: Thanks Steen. Been awhile since I logged in, but this is what I was looking for, and couldn't find so many days ago.